# Change CSS class property with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue.js and I want to change a CSS class property. 
The HTML code which uses the class is the following:

```
<div class="fillTimerBar"></div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
.fillTimerBar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 8px;
 }
```

From there I want to change the `width` class property using a `computed` property from the Vue component.

Which would be correct way if any?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to use `v-bind:style` directive.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
     width:'200px'
  },
  computed: {
    computedWidth: function () {
      return this.width;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeWidth: function (event) {
      this.width='100px';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#myDiv{
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <div id="myDiv" v-bind:style="{ width: computedWidth }"></div>
  <button v-on:click="changeWidth()">Change</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But in your case you changed direct style ,what about property inside class ?

Comment: what happened if there is something like text-decoration instead?

Answer (score 14):

To change a property inside a class, you can use CSS custom properties:

```
.fillTimerBar {
    --width: 100%;
    width: var(--width);
    height: 8px;
}
```

In Vue, you can bind CSS variables to the style:

```
<div class="fillTimerBar" :style="`--width: ${computedWidth}`"></div>
```

Comment: And for multiple variables in css you can use following:
`:style="\`--var-1: ${computed1}; --var-2: ${computed3}; --var-3: ${computed3};"\``

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain old javascript to add a new class to your div, then add css properties to elements that have the new class and your existing class. The CSS code if you wanted the width to be half (the more specific rule takes precedence):

```
.fillTimerBar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 8px;
 }
.fillTimerBar .HalfWidth {
        width: 50%;
 }
```